# Making Spotlight Search Bar like view in Objc/Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to replicate spotlight's view behaviour. Have added blurred adaptive background to NSWindow using:

```
NSVisualEffectView *visualEffectView =  [[NSVisualEffectView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
[visualEffectView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
visualEffectView.material = NSVisualEffectMaterialMediumLight;
visualEffectView.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectBlendingModeBehindWindow;
visualEffectView.wantsLayer = true;
visualEffectView.state = NSVisualEffectStateActive;
visualEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5;
[self addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

The problem is that background does work, but text and other elements inside the window don't adapt to the background below window correctly.

Here is the image.

[image: attached].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. By adding subviews to visualEffectView instead of self.